# Replication in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, replication

I started learning about spark and I came across a doubt about the replication in spark. I read spark is  a distributed computational framework and it does not have its own storage system like hadoop. My doubt is when a rdd is created partition are created and stored across multiple nodes in the cluster when there is a node failure in the spark cluster how spark handles it. Does spark have a replication concept or is there any other way spark to overcome this issue ?

I tried finding answer for this but there are different answers in internet some are saying spark uses a replication factor for eg "Replication in Apache Spark happens automatically when you create a Resilient Distributed Dataset (RDD)" and others are saying spark does not have a replication concept

Comment: there are multiple articles online that can provide the concept ([ref1](https://medium.com/@mrayandutta/fault-tolerance-in-apache-spark-beyond-replication-and-checkpointing-fd3ddfd54830#:~:text=Data%20Replication%3A&text=Such%20redundancy%20ensures%20that%20even,be%20accessed%20from%20a%20replica.&text=Setting%20the%20replication%20factor%20to,data%20availability%20despite%20node%20failures.)). spark's default replication factor is 1 (i think), and the same can be changed to a different number.

Comment: Watch this playlist. He explains the internals in a newbie friendly manner. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9dr6CYfJNc&list=PL_XpoDibuob5VwS4pHIi_4L9ojwAO49TV&index=1

Comment: just to highlight, "replication" is a storage concept and spark is a framework that can work with multiple storage solutions. spark can toggle replication of the storage it is using.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the question!!

RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset) is resilient, i.e. fault-tolerant, and distributed, i.e. stored in different machines. How this works is that Spark creates a DAG (Direct Acyclic Graph) from the original dataset to the intended RDD.

Let me explain this with an example. Let's say we are trying to run the following operation.

```
val df = spark.read.json("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/sourav/sample_data.json")
val df2 = df.select("name")
df2.show()
```

In this case, we are trying to read `name` column from the JSON file and display that. Although it says that the `df` variable will store data read from the JSON file, it will not do it (Spark works on lazy evaluation), it will create a DAG and store it in memory. In the second line, it will again create a DAG and store it in memory. Finally, in the third line it will perform actual operations and display the output. These DAGs are stored in Driver memory, so it is a kind of single point of failure (we see this kind of OOM failure in our production jobs, when the Driver JVM is overloaded we lose the DAG definitions).

I hope this explanation clarifies your doubt.

Comment: this answer has nothing about "replication" that the OP's question wants to understand